# Concatenation with arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist, concatenation

This is my code. I know how to use the `concat` operator, but not with arrays or `arraylist`.

```
import java.util.*;
class stringProject {
    static String concat(String str1, String str2) {
        return str1.concat(str2);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
      ArrayList<String> projectStrings = new ArrayList<String>();
      projectStrings.add("The ");
      projectStrings.add("quick ");
      projectStrings.add("brown ");
      projectStrings.add("fox ");
      projectStrings.add("jumped ");
      projectStrings.add("over ");
      projectStrings.add("the ");
      projectStrings.add("lazy ");
      projectStrings.add("dog.");
    }
    System.out.println(projectStrings.get(1).concat(projectStrings.get(0)));
    }
}
```

And my errors are:

```
File: C:\Users\Daniel\stringProject.java  [line: 23]
Error: Syntax error on token "println", Identifier expected after this token
File: C:\Users\Daniel\stringProject.java  [line: 23]
Error: Syntax error on tokens, AnnotationName expected instead
File: C:\Users\Daniel\stringProject.java  [line: 23]
Error: Syntax error on token ")", delete this token
File: C:\Users\Daniel\stringProject.java  [line: 23]
Error: Syntax error, insert "Type VariableDeclaratorId" to complete FormalParameter
File: C:\Users\Daniel\stringProject.java  [line: 23]
Error: Syntax error, insert ")" to complete MethodDeclaration
File: C:\Users\Daniel\stringProject.java  [line: 25]
Error: Syntax error on token "}", delete this token
```

Comment: `System.out.println(projectStrings.get(1).concat(projectStrings.get(0)));`?

Comment: Sorry, I have been following error messages and I have no idea what to do there.

Comment: @BackSlash AFAIK `String` does not have an `append` method, that's `StringBuilder` and `StringBuffer`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problems in your current code:

1. You have to define you're working with a list of `String`s. You can do this by adding the `String` generic in your `ArrayList` declaration, otherwise you're declaring a raw `ArrayList`, thus all the elements will be treated as `Object`s:

   ```
   ArrayList<String> projectStrings = new ArrayList<String>();
   ```

   or the Java 7 way, using the diamond operator:

   ```
   ArrayList<String> projectStrings = new ArrayList<>();
   ```
2. You haven't defined a `concat` method in your code. Probably you want to use [`String#concat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#concat%28java.lang.String%29):

   ```
   System.out.println(projectStrings.get(1).concat(projectStrings(0)));
   ```

Another way to concat `String`s is by using the `+` symbol:

```
System.out.println(projectStrings.get(1) + projectStrings(0));
```

Just in case you want your current code to work, define a `concat` method outside the `main` method:

```
class stringProject {
    //this method should be static in order to be used in other static methods like main
    static String concat(String str1, String str2) {
        //naive implementation
        return str1.concat(str2);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //your current code here...
        //since you have defined a concat method, you can use it with no problems
        System.out.println(concat(projectStrings.get(1), projectStrings.get(0)));
    }
}
```

Another advice: you don't need to add `import java.lang.*`, this is added by default by the compiler, so you can remove this line.

---

After your code edit, you closed the `main` method just before printing your output. This is how your code looks now:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{ //this is where your main method starts
  ArrayList<String> projectStrings = new ArrayList<String>();
  projectStrings.add("The ");
  projectStrings.add("quick ");
  projectStrings.add("brown ");
  projectStrings.add("fox ");
  projectStrings.add("jumped ");
  projectStrings.add("over ");
  projectStrings.add("the ");
  projectStrings.add("lazy ");
  projectStrings.add("dog.");
} //this is where your main method ends
//this line is outside any method, thus you get those errors
System.out.println(projectStrings.get(1).concat(projectStrings.get(0)));
} //this is where your stringProject class definition ends
```

Solution: just move that `System.out.println(...)` line inside your `main` method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{ //this is where your main method starts
  ArrayList<String> projectStrings = new ArrayList<String>();
  projectStrings.add("The ");
  projectStrings.add("quick ");
  projectStrings.add("brown ");
  projectStrings.add("fox ");
  projectStrings.add("jumped ");
  projectStrings.add("over ");
  projectStrings.add("the ");
  projectStrings.add("lazy ");
  projectStrings.add("dog.");
  //easy fix
  System.out.println(projectStrings.get(1).concat(projectStrings.get(0)));
} //this is where your main method ends
} //this is where your stringProject class definition ends
```

Comment: @YoungDeezie please [**edit your question**](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/21337069/edit) and add your current code to see where the errors may be.

Comment: @YoungDeezie I've updated my answer. Please be more careful next time, happy coding :).

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need to understand how ArrayList's work.  You are probably trying to do this:

```
ArrayList<String> projectStrings = new ArrayList<String>();
```

...

```
System.out.println(projectStrings.get(1).concat(projectStrings.get(0)));
```

Comment: This returns the error The method concat(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object) is undefined for the type stringProject

Comment: `concat` is a method from the `String` API, it should be `projectStrings.get(1).concat(projectStrings.get(0))`

Comment: @BackSlash `String#concat` is, but `concat` alone isn't.

Answer (score 1):

All you need is simply

```
ArrayList<String> projectStrings = new ArrayList<>();
//populate as needed
System.out.println(projectStrings.get(0) + projectStrings.get(1));
```

if you want to use `ArrayList`.

Note my use of generics. The `ArrayList` you defined is a collection of `Object`. Mine is a collection of `String`. Doing it your way costs you compile-time guarantees and also makes some of the other answers unworkable.

Comment: Good point.  I didn't notice that he didn't declare the ArrayList as ArrayList<String>.  That should fix his issues.